# How to solve com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE

Tags: android, usb-debugging, mi

I am using Mi Note3, before that, I can run the code from react-native using react-native run-android and connect with my phone. Now cannot already. My MIUI version is 10.2, I already open Developer options, USB debugging, Install via USB and turn off the MIUI optimization.

Comment: have you checked version of you

Comment: Thank you for your reply, which version? for phone or react native?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens when you try to update a signed release build with a debug build for instance. apk cannot be installed because its signature is incompatible with the currently installed version.The solution is to uninstall the existing app from the device.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall application once and then  run command react-native run-android after connecting device.